# JAX-B - Create @XmlElement for one resource method and not for other method from same class

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jax-rs

I'm new to JAX-RS and JAX-B and I having problems with the following situation:

I have an entity class and it's resource class.

My resource class has two methods. Both method "uses" the same entity class, but theres a field I need only in one method.

```
public class Item {
    ....
    @XmlElement(name="fieldName")
    public void getFieldName(){
        return fieldName;        
    }
    ...
}

@Path("items")
public class ItemResource {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public public Response methodA(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
        //this method will use fieldName
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public public Response methodB(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
        //this method will not use fieldName
    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem? Is there a way to "choose the context" I can use a field annotated with @XmlElement ?

I'm using jersey-media-json-jackson...

Comment: This is not impossible but quite hard. Would be easier to define two separate classes. One of the could subclass the other one and add the needed field.

Comment: Using DTO would be a good idea for this context?

Comment: You can call the DTO if you wish.

Comment: Thanks! a DTO worked for me...I've read a lot of bad things about DTO and I was kind of worried to use it but...anyway it solved my problem...